# integrating a plug-in into moodle

Tags: video, moodle, plugins

am tryng to integrate a video plug-in into moodle.
But i tried copying the plug-in  to the /mod/ directory. But still,our module has not been included under notifications in Moodle.

We consulted the MOODLE site for help,
  "http://docs.moodle.org/en/Installing_contributed_modules_or_plugins" and followed the instruction: 1)Visit your Local Moodle site http://localhost:8888/moodle19/ ,

2)go to Site Administration,3) go to Notifications, 4)Scroll to the bottom of the page and 5)click on "Continue".

But the fact is that ,neither is our module appearing under notifications and nor is continue coming.....
Could somebody let me know what the problem could be coz i had no error coming..
Also pls help me solve this problem.
Awaiting an effective solution............

Comment: sidsag, I'm having the same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What's the name of the module directory? I'm not sure if it's still the case, but Moodle only used to work with module directories that were all lower case. If that isn't the problem could you post your mod directory structure (the structure underneath your mod root directory)?